# Submit event not triggerd in mobile device when keyboard is shown

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, forms

Using Jquery 1.11.1 I am sending an ajax request on form submit:

```
...
contactForm.on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({...});
...
```

The form is a ContactForm formed by an input text, a textarea and a submit button.

Running in **desktop mode** (Chrome, Firefox, IE,...) there is no problem: the submit event is triggered and the ajax call works well.

When I submit the form **in mobile device** (Android, Ios,...) while the keyboard is shown the form is not submited. 
If I hide the keyboard and then I tap in submit button the form is submited and the ajax call works fine.

The problem is the submit event is not triggered when in a mobile device the keyboard is shown.

You can see in the screenshot the keyboard show (green button is the submit):
[image: The button is green]

Comment: How do you focus on submit button on mobile device? When you put a focus does the keyboard available to hit enter?

Comment: If I scroll down the page the keyboard is shown and I can tap the green button

Comment: Have the same issue. Did you solve this?

Comment: It seems that it helps me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306818/form-submit-button-event-is-not-captured-when-keyboard-is-up-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

(I had the same issue but in a different scenario, therefor I've described it differently and posted a new question: [Android Chrome click after keyboard entry not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64280854/android-chrome-click-after-keyboard-entry-not-working/64312739#64312739))

The solution boils down to this piece of JavaScript that triggeres a `blur()` on the input elements/textareas:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea').forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    e.target.blur();
    e.target.focus();
  })
})
```