# Input/Button of type submit brings up the virtual keyboard

Tags: html, iphone, forms

I've made a contact form with a `<input type="submit" />`. The odd thing is that on my Iphone the virtual keyboard triggers when submitting the form using this button.

How can i prevent the virtual keyboard from appearing when I submit the form?

Comment: I think that we need more code in order to help you. Could you set up a minimal example that triggers that behavior? Often mobile device browsers focus a form input (the first on the page?) automatically when you enter a page. Maybe pressing the submit button and staying on the page leads to some kind of that auto focus.

Comment: See if you wrapped it in form tag properly, cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange, but it is possible that iphone see this input as a text input. it could be a javascript or jquery code, could be a bug, could be anythig. If jQuery is an option creat a button and bind it to submit, try below and let us know what happens

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306818/form-submit-button-event-is-not-captured-when-keyboard-is-up-ios-7)

```
$(document).on('touchend', 'form #button', function (e) {
    $('#formID').submit();
});
```

Create a button, apparently it is a safari issue

```
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="form.submit();" />
```